# hub 8-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)

Tags: boot, usb

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 on a newly build PC dual booting Windows on a second hard drive. Whenever I boot into my Ubuntu drive, it first reports the error "hub 8-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)".

Over the next ~40 seconds, it reports the following error about 3-4 times:
"usb 1-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110".

Then once it does this, it finally brings me to the login screen with no more issue. I've confirmed all USB ports (both A and C) are functional on my motherboard. I've also attempted to boot my computer with nothing plugged in other than my monitors via DisplayPort and my speakers via the 3.5mm audio out, but the errors above still showed. My motherboard has been updated to its latest firmware.

Can someone help me figure out how to solve this?

EDIT: Just realized it's probably important to note that my motherboard is an MSI MAG B650 Tomahawk Wifi.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem. Messages and not errors.

Comment: getting the same message with a similar board: MPG B650I EDGE WIFI. Have you made any progress on this?

Comment: same in SUS ROG STRIX B650-A GAMING, Debian 12 (kernel 6.1.0-10-amd64)

Comment: same issue with ASUS B650e-e and Ubuntu 23.

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution for this issue? I'm facing a similar error, but instead of 'hub 8-0:1.0,' I'm encountering 'hbu 12-0:1.0,' and I'm unable to proceed with the Ubuntu installation.

You can find my question and details on this problem here: [hbu 12-0:1.0: Config Failed - Hub Doesn't Have Any Ports (Error -19)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1484830/hbu-12-01-0-config-failed-hub-doesnt-have-any-ports-error-19).

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem.
Debian kernel 6.1 does not boot with Ryzen 7900 and Asus b650e.
"hub does not have ports" was the error and freezes there.

Debian kernel 5.10 boots, but does not detect the igpu properly, can't change screen resolution up.

So I think Ryzen 7000 does not work yet with Debian 11 kernel 6 and iGPU is the problem.

Comment: Yeah same here. ASUS b650 and r9 7900, debian 12

Comment: I'm also getting a similar error and I believe this issue may be related to USB-C, as I came across a similar question where a user was encountering a related error:

```
hub 6-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)
```

You can find the question and details at this link: [USB-C Ports Suddenly Stopped Working on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1484724/usb-c-ports-suddenly-stopped-working-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: In the same boat. Curiously, it can start up if I start the system in recovery mode then boot normally after that.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with Unbuntu 22.04 on an MAG B650 Tomahawk Wifi (MS-7D75)

Linux  kernel 5.19.0-32

A windows install worked just fine. I was able to get it going with the most recent firmware build: 7D75v164(Beta version)
https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MAG-B650-TOMAHAWK-WIFI/support#bios

It's a beta, so be careful, but it worked. The previous version I had on the board when I got it was 7D75v13.

Comment: Still an issue for me, you got it resolved?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly this error during boot on a fairly new Ubuntu 22.04 installation. It was caused by the kernel update from 5.19.0-41 to 5.19.0-46. I had no GRUB boot menu, and couldn't find any way to interrupt startup to obtain one.

I followed the instructions [here](https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-22-04-not-booting-troubleshooting-guide) to use `boot-repair` to perform the "Recommended repair", thus setting up a GRUB I could interact with.

I can now manually select 5.19.0-41-generic to boot successfully.

Googling suggests that my problems are related to use of nvidia and that booting with `nomodeset` may be a work around (see [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/arch-29/arch-linux-installation-hardware-errors-4175723710/)). I think I'll just see if it persists with the next kernel update before I try any harder.

Comment: I also think that the problem is related to Nvidia. I had the exact same issue but when I swapped out the graphics card for a new AMD Radeon card, the problem was gone.

Comment: Can also confirm problem from nivdia: Forced internal graphics (forced IGFX) and the system booted up normally.