# USB-C ports suddenly stopped working ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel

As the title suggests my USB-C ports suddenly stopped working without a reboot of my computer.

The only function of the USB-C ports that works right now is charging, USB3.0 ports work fine. As it worked before I wonder if it's a hardware issue or a issue with ubuntu or the linux kernel.

Some error messages in the log file that might indicate the issue:

```
hub 6-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)
ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: ucsi_acpi_dsm: failed to evaluate _DSM 2
```

I'm using a Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 Pro with AMD Ryzen 9 6900hs creator edition
My kernel is 6.2.0-32-generic

Comment: The same error is preventing me from booting at startup. I also have a Lenovo, with AMD Ryzen 5 Pro :/