# Can't boot on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: boot, drivers, 22.04, startup

I can't boot on Ubuntu anymore and I'm not sure why.
The only information I have are those messages in the console.

```
[0.270919] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [SB.PCIO.GPP7.U POO.DP40.UP00.DP68], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/dswload2-162)
[ 0.270935] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/ps object-220)
[ 0.994566] hub 10-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)
/dev/nvme0n1p6: clean, 217750/19709952 files, 4807020/78812928 blocks
```

When I choose Ubuntu in GRUB, it displays this and an underscore blinks then stops.

I can launch the OS if I boot via the recoverymode and then choose normal boot.
I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu but it changed nothing.

I'm not sure if it's true but I saw somewhere that it might be a graphic driver issue, I have a 7000 series AMD graphic card.

If someone has any advice, i'll gladly take them.

Comment: Yes, it might be a graphic driver issue. Maybe the latest upgrade of the linux kernel caused a problem for your computer's graphics. I guess that you still have the previous kernel, and you should be able to boot into it via the grub menu. If that works, please avoid deleting that kernel version.

Comment: The only other kernel version that I have is 6.2.0-26 and it doesn't work too. Is there a way to download an older version ?

Comment: What happens if you add the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `acpi=off` ?

Comment: I just tried it and it booted normally but I only have one monitor (instead of 2) limited to 90hz and without vsync working like when I launch in recovery mode

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hub 8-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1463310/hub-8-01-0-config-failed-hub-doesnt-have-any-ports-err-19)

Comment: I don't know if you need other commands or modifications, but you can try `sudo apt install linux-image-5.19.0-41-generic` (according to an answer in the linked thread). The following command line shows all available linux images, `apt-cache policy linux-image*generic|grep ^linux|sort` or without the unsigned kernels, `apt-cache policy linux-image*generic|grep ^linux|grep -v unsigned|sort`

Comment: I tried launching with an older kernel and it behaved the same way as launching with acpi=off. I tried running boot-repair as in the other thread without any success.

Comment: It is possible that some software, for example some piece of the firmware, was upgraded too (not only the kernel), and this caused the problem. It is difficult to help without access to the same hardware as yours. Let us hope that someone with the same or similar hardware will see your question and offer useful advice.

Comment: By the way (I am only guessing here), are you using Wayland or X for the graphics? You can switch according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428525/how-to-permanetely-disable-wayland/1428532#1428532) in order to test the other alternative.

Comment: I was using Wayland, switching to Xorg didn't change anything and installing AMD's driver didn't make any change so I decided to switch to Debian until there is a reliable fix and it seems to work fine for now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm glad that you found a solution within the Linux community :-)